# Can I make the program read ' . ' if the user puts ' , ' ? Using C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a code where the user has to put the price for the liters of paint... But it only accepts prices like "2.50", can I make the program convert a comma into a point if the user puts "2,50"? Using C!

```
    printf ("\n How many liters of green paint we'll use? ");
    scanf ("%d", &green);
    printf ("\n How many liters of blue paint we'll use? ");
    scanf (" %d", &blue);
    printf ("\n What's the price for the liter of green paint? ");
    scanf ("%f", &priceG);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("\n What's the price for the liter of blue paint? ");
    scanf ("%f", &priceB);
```

Comment: You have to change your _locale_. See e.g. [`setlocale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale).

Answer (score 1):

collect the input into a **string** and perform the operation..

Traverse each character of the string and if you come across `,` replace it with `.`

Put the traversed characters into an other **string** while traversing and when `,` is found, replace it with `.`

This procedure might be lengthy, but it might help and meet your requirement.

Comment: would you please add the neccessary casts required during this whole procedure

Comment: @t3n: traversing through a string and putting it into another doesn't need any cast.. After the completion of this, you can use atof to convert the string to float..

Comment: "After the completion of this, you can use atof to convert the string to float".... i was looking for something like this...thanx for the clarifications ..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the desired locale for the decimal point using `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"yourLocale")` from `#include <locale.h>`. ([more infos here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/))

`yourLocale` has to be a valid locale string that is available on your machine and uses the `,` as decimal point, for example `de_DE`. You can get available locales with `locale -a`.